# How to call from one call back function to other call back function

Tags: jquery

I am trying to call from one call back function to other.Both are in ready function. how to do that.Here is code I am trying:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $("#addRow").bind('click',function add(){
            //do something

            $("#qty1").click(function(){

                 add();//I can call from here
            });
       });

       $("#qty2").click( function(){

            //I want call add()  from here
       });

});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with same code structure, without defining a function outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create standalone function declaration:

```
function add(){
  .....
}
```

And call where needed:

```
$("#AddRow").click(add);
$("#qty2").click(add);
```

If your `add` function also accepts ***arguments***, then you will have to call it like this:

```
$("#AddRow").click(function(){
  add(a, b);
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with same structure, without creating a standalone function

Comment: @tutor777: No it is not possible that way unfortunately because your function only exists in first click handler and also it is function expression not function declaration so it won't be available elsewhere. You will have to modify your code.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function outside your jQuery:

```
function add() {
  // stuff goes here
}
```

And then you'll be able to call it in your jQuery functions:

```
$("#qty2").click( function(){
    add();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       var add = function(){

             //do something

       }

        $("#qty1").click(function(){

                 add();//I can call from here
         });
       $("#addRow").bind('click',function(){add();});

       $("#qty2").click( function(){

           add();
       });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your function first, then attach it to any events you like:

```
function add(event) {
  // Your code...
}

$("#addRow").click(add);
$("#qty2").click(add);
```